# Move File in parent directory

Tags: php, move

I think the image says everything, but will explain my problem, I uploaded some images over php on the server and they are uploaded on the PHP directory (I don't know why), now I want to move them in the "sister" directory Bilder and their "child" Beschreibung.[image]

```
     $query ="SELECT id FROM hausaufgaben ORDER BY id ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$id = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$id = $row['id'];
}

$path = "Beschreibung_$id.png";

$actualpath = "http://mywebsite.com/Hausaufgabenplaner/Bilder/Beschreibung/$path";


$mydate=getdate(date("U"));
$Erstellungsdatum = "$mydate[weekday], $mydate[mday] $mydate[month], $mydate[year]";


$query = " Insert into hausaufgaben(beschreibung,Abgabedatum,Erstellungsdatum,Fach,DeviceID, Beschreibung_Image) values ('$beschreibung','$Abgabedatum', '$Erstellungsdatum','$Fach','$DeviceID','$image');";
         if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        rename("$path", "/Hausaufgabenplaner/Bilder/Beschreibung/$path");
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }


    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: @mistermartin I can think of a few. Single quotes around variables.. `$path` containing a full path, not just the file name..

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't move, $path is the name of the picture e.g.  Image.jpg

Comment: Explain more please

Comment: It doesn't move because you're using single quotes. The variables are passed as literal strings. Try using double quotes instead.

Comment: added few more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I uploaded some images over php on the server and they are uploaded on the PHP directory (I don't know why)

Based on the code you provided, this is how you are uploading the image:

```
$path = "Beschreibung_$id.png";
file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
```

There is no directory specified, therefore the image will be written to the same directory as the PHP file currently running.

> now I want to move them in the "sister" directory Bilder and their "child" Beschreibung.

Again, based on the code you provided:

```
rename("$path", "/Hausaufgabenplaner/Bilder/Beschreibung/$path");
```

You're only specifying the relative path, not the absolute path. So this will translate to: `/Current Directory/Hausaufgabenplaner/Bilder/Beschreibung/$path`

You can find the absolute path by echoing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: thank you for this answer, is it possible to upload them immediately to the "Beschreibung" folder?

Comment: @rib Yes, first find your absolute path. Might look something like this `/var/www/public_html/Hausaufgabenplaner/Bilder/Beschreibung/` then you can modify your statement: `file_put_contents($absolute_path . $image_title, base64_decode($image))`